# python and dynamic imports of sub directories

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a data structure that looks like this in python 2.7

```
myfile.py
--parsers
  --folder1
    file1.py
         def filemethod(data=None)
            pass
```

Under the folder parsers, I can add many subfolders

I will always know then name of the function I want to call however

How do I do an import the parser directory so I can find the methods in each of the sub directory and accessible from myfile.py.    I use getattr to convert a name to a function object.  This is necessary because I get the name of the function to call from a remote call to a redis queue.

```
import ??????
methodToCall = getattr('filemethod', 'file1')
methodToCall(data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to do dynamic imports is using `imp.load_source()`:

```
import imp
module = imp.load_source( 'mymodule', module_full_path )
```

in your case it will be something like:

```
module = imp.load_source( 'file1', '.\parsers\file1.py')
methodToCall = getattr( module, 'filemethod' )
methodToCall( data )
```

Make sure you replace `'file1'` and `'.\parsers\file1.py'` with your desired module name and the correct path to its source file.

Comment: Of all the methods I've tried dynamically loading from a subdirectory modules that are referenced in a config file, this is the only one that I could get to work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to first import the subdirectories from `parsers/__init__.py`.

`parsers/__init__.py`:

```
import folder1
import folder2
...
```

then:

```
import parsers
foldername = 'folder1'  # for example
mod = getattr(parsers, foldername)
methodToCall = getattr(mod, 'filemethod')
methodToCall(data)
```